# Why are the rows and columns of an invertible square matrix linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have come across this statement in my textbook that the rows and columns of an invertible square matrix are linearly independent, but I am still unsure why.

Comment: An invertible matrix must have full rank. (Otherwise it is not a bijection, and thus not invertible) A matrix with full rank has linearly independent rows. For columns, use the fact that the transpose of a invertible matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement (for columns) is the same as "if $M$ is invertible, then its columns are independent."

Consider the contrapositive statement: "if $M$'s columns are dependent, then $M$ is noninvertible."

If $M$'s columns are dependent, then for some collection of scalars $c_i$, not all equal to $0$, $$c_1\vec{\text{col}_1}+c_2\vec{\text{col}_2}+\cdots+c_n\vec{\text{col}_n}=0$$ which is the same as $$\left[\vec{\text{col}_1}\ \vec{\text{col}_2}\ \cdots\ \vec{\text{col}_n}\right]\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\ c_n\end{bmatrix}$$ which demonstrates a nonzero vector that $M$ annihilates. So you can conclude that $M$ is noninvertible (because it maps at least two things to the zero vector.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be an invertible square matrix (of size $n\times n$) whose $i$-th line is $L_i$. By contradiction, assume that the lines of $M$ are not linearly independent. Then, there exists $X=(\alpha_i)$ a nonzero column vector such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iL_i=0$, that is $MX=0$. Left-multiplying by $M^{-1}$, one gets $X=0$, which is a contradiction.

With some minor adjustments (that I leave to you), the same argument holds for the columns of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the determinant of an invertible matrix is different of 0. Also remember that the determinant is built as a function to generalize the concept of volume. If $d $ is a determinant function of an n-dimensional space, you give it n vectors representing the sides of a n-dimensional rectangle and it returns its volume.

Now take the example of $R^3$. You can pick any three vectors $v_i, i=1,2,3$ and we can think of the solid they generate:

the set $\{ P \in R^3 : P = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3, 0 \le \alpha_i \le 1, \alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3 = 1 \}$ and its volume. Now if all three vectors lay on some plane, then the solid they generate has no "height" and therefore the volume "collapses" and it is 0.

If you extend that ideia and define the columns of the matrix as the vectors that generate some solid, then having linearly *dependant* columns is the analogue to having those 3 vectors in the plane, making one of the dimensions of the solid to "collapse" and setting its n-dimensional volume to 0. If all columns are *independent* then your solid does not collapse and its determinant is not 0.

Using that motivation to build the determinant function, one can show its uniqueness aside from a scalar factor. We eliminate that problem by saying that the n-dimensional "cube" with sides of length 1 has volume 1 *i.e.* the determinant of the identity matrix is 1. With all that in mind one deduces a formula to calculate the determinant of a matrix that works both for columns and for rows. And therefore you get that the determinant is not 0 when both columns and rows are linearly independent. And when one happens, the other does to. So either both columns and rows are linearly independat or both columns and rows are linearly dependant.

Comment: In my opinion, using the determinant is not exactly the right call here. Indeed, the notion of determinant requires some theory to be made up, whereas linearity independance and invertible matrices are only definitions. However, if one has some notions on the determinant, your answer is great.

Comment: @C.Falcon I must agree with you. I only gave that answer because that was how I was first introduced to the determinant and invertible matrices. Your answer does look simpler.